# How to submit WordCount.jar to hadoop via servlet

Tags: java, hadoop, servlets

I now have a WordCount.jar stored in the linux local file system and a file containing a set of words stored in HDFS .
How can i run this WordCount.jar through a servlet and specify the input and output paths in the servlet.

```
    package org.apache.hadoop.examples;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

public class WordCount {

  public static class TokenizerMapper 
       extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
      while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(itr.nextToken());
        context.write(word, one);
      }
    }
  }

  public static class IntSumReducer 
       extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, 
                       Context context
                       ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      int sum = 0;
      for (IntWritable val : values) {
        sum += val.get();
      }
      result.set(sum);
      context.write(key, result);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
    if (otherArgs.length < 2) {
      System.err.println("Usage: wordcount <in> [<in>...] <out>");
      System.exit(2);
    }
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    for (int i = 0; i < otherArgs.length - 1; ++i) {
      FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[i]));
    }
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,
      new Path(otherArgs[otherArgs.length - 1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally following steps

1. Put your wordcount class jar file to your server classpath as well as necessary hadoop client jar files
2. Specify the input and output dir as http request argument
3. Parse the dirs from http request in your servlet doGet() method
4. Use [JobClient](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobClient.html) to submit your job

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your answer .Just now I have solved the problem  by reference to this [blog](http://www.cnblogs.com/spork/archive/2010/04/12/1710294.html)

First add hadoop configuration files and jars to classpath then  use org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar() method to get the jar submit to mapreduce framework.

I have encountered a problem because  System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);  causes jvm to close and tomcat is closed.When I delete system.exit() .It works fine.